# Which is better when using EF, select multiple times or using include?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities, one is `box` and the other is `tennis`. There is a foreign key `BoxID` in table `tennis`, that is to say, a `tennis` must be in a `box`, and the `box` is a collection of `tennis`.

Now that I know a `tennis ID`, I need to check the `name` of the `box` to which this `tennis` belongs. I have two options.

Option A: First find the attribute of this `tennis` in the `tennis` table, get the `BoxID`, and then go to the `box` table to find the attribute of the `box`.

```
var tennisId = 12345;

// Option A:
var tennis = await dbContext.TennisTable
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == tennisId);

var box = await dbContext.BoxTable
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == tennis.BoxID);

return box.Name;
```

Option B: Directly use the `Include` syntax of `EF Core` to find the `tennis` and the `box` to which it belongs, to get the properties of the `box`.

```
// Option B:

var tennis = await dbContext.TennisTable
        .Include(t => t.Box);
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == tennisId);

return tennis.Box.Name;
```

In the large-scale practice, which of the above two methods has more performance advantages?

`large-scale` means that the questions may be much more complicated in real use cases. The count of `box` and `tennis` may be billions.

Comment: define: `large-scale`

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: To many maybes. If you are trying to solve already existing problem with your code, then please post the code. Looking into the future is off topic here.

Comment: @FCin: While the options should have been given with a code example, the question isn't so much looking to the future but rather realizing there's more than one way to do it and not knowing which one is the better approach. OP has done the legwork of coming up with the two approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. You don't need an `Include` statement here.

The `Include` statement should be used when you want to **retrieve additional related entities**. But that is not what you want:

> I need to check the name of the box to which this tennis belongs.

You only need the `Box` object to read its name. You don't need to load any additional entities.

```
var boxName = db.TennisTable
                .Where(t => t.Id == tennisId)
                .Select(t => t.Box.Name)
                .Single();
```

*If you need to account for the tennis object possibly not existing without throwing an exception, use `SingleOrDefault()` instead of `Single()`.*

In other words:

- **Find all tennis objects with this ID**. We know there is only one, but by using `Where` instead of `Single`, EF does not yet query the database and it can keep using an `IQueryable` instead.
- For all found entries, **select the name of its box**. Again, we know there's one entry, but EF will still not instantiate the query because you're not enumerating the `IQueryable` yet.
- **Take the first result**. We know it's the only result, but now EF will hit the database with a single (combined) call instead of two separate ones.

If you had used `Include` logic, you would've retrieved the entire tennis and box objects. My answer only retrieves the box name, which is a significant reduction of data transfer size between the database and your application.

If you had used two calls, you would've loaded both the tennis and box object **and** you would've had to do two calls, which means increased data transfer size **and** lowered performance due to additional network calls.

Comment: What if I both need the name of the `tennis` and the name of the `box`?

Comment: Assuming you only need the names: `.Select(t => new { BoxName = t.Box.Name, TennisName = t.Name})` and then your resulting object will have the needed `BoxName` and `TennisName` properties.